# Want to update database without using primary key in my table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

**What to do it shows error "The property 'AvailableSeats' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified."**
I know that error comes bescause I don't have primary key in my table but what is the alternative solution to it beacause we as a team working on project and now at the end time if I do change in the database then we can't able to sync or merge our projects with each other. Please help me out guys.

**This is my asp.net mvc controller:-**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Boolean))]
public IHttpActionResult PutAmount(CancelFlightDetails c3)
{
    try
    {
        var amount = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == c3.Name && f.TicketNumber == c3.TicketNumber);
        var amount1 = db.SeatsAvailabilities.FirstOrDefault(g => g.DepartureDate == c3.DepartureDate && g.FlightNumber == amount.FlightNumber);
        var amount2 = db.SeatsAvailabilities.SingleOrDefault(g => g.DepartureDate == c3.DepartureDate && g.FlightNumber == amount.FlightNumber); ;

        if (c3.DepartureDate == DateTime.Now.Date && amount2 != null)
        {
            amount2.AvailableSeats += 1;
            amount2.TotalRevenue += c3.FareDetails;
            db.Entry(amount2).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.SeatsAvailabilities.Remove(amount1);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(true);
        }
        else
        {
            amount2.AvailableSeats ++;
            amount2.ExtraRevenue += (decimal)0.6 * amount2.FareDetails;
            amount2.TotalRevenue += amount2.ExtraRevenue;
            db.Entry(amount2).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.SeatsAvailabilities.Remove(amount1);
            //db.Entry(amount2).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
        //return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Sql Server not connected");
    }
}
```

**So, First I tried with EntityState.Modified but it throws error that i shown above and then I try to overwrite by adding new object and deleting previous one but still same error.**

Comment: Solution is to get the team together and agree to all make changes so that it will work. Not having a primary key on your table is almost always (with occasional exceptions) a fundamental problem which needs resolving rather than working round. Obviously we don't actually know your schema properly from what you've shown, but if AvailableSeats is supposed to be a changeable value, then it seems unlikely it should be part of the key for the table. You appear to have a design flaw of some sort. It will need sorting. Having other team members to work with is not a reason to avoid that.

Comment: ORMs like Entity Framework work based on certain conventions. EF and LINQ aren't a replacement for ADO.NET and SQL, they are ORMs that work in a very specific way, for some very specific scenarios. Having a primary key for entities is a fundamental requirement. If the way EF works doesn't suit your use case *don't user it* - you don't have to. Use a different library or even ADO.NET.

Comment: BTW not having a PK in a table named `SeatAvailabilities` means you're going to double-sell and have to refund some very irate customers. No matter how many tests and checks you use, you'll end up with duplicate entries.